# Domain errors with Maximize/NMaximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to maximize a (somewhat) complicated function over probability distribution $p$ and $q$. Here is my input:

```
Maximize[{(p0 q2 + p2 q0)^0.5 + (p0 q1 + p1 q0)^0.5 + (p1 q3 + p3 q1)^0.5 
           + (p2 q3 + p3 q2)^0.5, 
          (0 <= p0 <= 1) && (0 <= p1 <= 1) && (0 <= p2 <= 1) && (0 <= p3 <= 1) && 
          (0 <= q0 <= 1) && (0 <= q1 <= 1) && (0 <= q2 <= 1) && (0 <= q3 <= 1) &&
          (p0 + p1 + p2 + p3 == 1) && (q0 + q1 + q2 + q3 == 1)}, 
          {p0, p1, p2, p3, q0, q1, q2, q3}] // N
```

However, I get this error:

> ```
> NMaximize::nrnum: "The function value -0.862277-0.353837 I is not a real number at
> { p0, p1, p2, p3, q0, q1, q2, q3} = { -0.00823803, 0.168927, 0.643765, 0.195547,
>                                       -0.0740624, 0.571036, 0.228872, 0.274154  }."
> ```

I find this odd, since I thought the constraints should disallow that.
Oddly enough, `FindMaximum` works fine.

Comment: Someone better versed than me probably knows the answer, but even when I specified the intervals using `{{p0, 0, 1}, {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, {p3, 0, 1}, {q0, 0, 1}, {q1, 0, 
  1}, {q2, 0, 1}, {q3, 0, 1}}` it still gave an error because it started using some negative values of the variables, so I'm not sure why it's starting the maximization in a location that's outside the specified bounds...

Comment: Also, since your expression has things to the power of 0.5 (which is numeric), it's automatically calling `NMaximize`, rather than `Maximize`, so the `N` is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get an answer:

```
NMaximize[{Sqrt[Abs[p0 q2 + p2 q0]] + Sqrt[Abs[p0 q1 + p1 q0]] + 
   Sqrt[Abs[p1 q3 + p3 q1]] + Sqrt[Abs[p2 q3 + p3 q2]], 
   (0 < p0 < 1) && (0 < p1 < 1) && (0 < p2 < 1) && (0 < p3 < 1) && (0 < q0 < 1) && 
   (0 < q1 < 1) && (0 < q2 < 1) && (0 < q3 < 1) && (p0 + p1 + p2 + p3 == 1) && 
   (q0 + q1 + q2 + q3 == 1)}, {p0, p1, p2, p3, q0, q1, q2, q3}]

{2., {p0 -> -7.93258*10^-10, p1 -> 0.5, p2 -> 0.5, p3 -> 0., 
  q0 -> 0.5, q1 -> 0., q2 -> 0., q3 -> 0.5}}
```

You can see that the constraint does get violated (somewhat) in the p0 term which is effectively/numerically zero, but in reality slightly negative.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but since I am new to mathematica stack exchange, I don't have enough rep yet to upvote your answer.